# Lebesgue Integral calculating problem

Tags: lebesgue-integral

$$
\lim _{ n->\infty  }{ \int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ { (1+nx^{ 2 })(1+x^{ 2 })^{ -n }\quad  }dx }  } 
$$

Please help me calculating the limit.
Integral is Lebesgue Integral and what I learnt is Bounded convergence theorem

Comment: By Bernoulli's inequality, the integrand is $\leqslant 1$.

Comment: I think the limit is 0,since the integrand converges to 0 pointwise. But I have a problem proving the pointwise limit is 0... Is this right anyways?

Comment: You've asked an [almost identical question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798740/lebesgue-integrable-functions-and-calculating-the-limit) just hours ago...

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_n(x) = \frac{1 + nx^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$, then $1 + nx^2 \leq n + nx^2= n(1+x^2) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ a.e..  We also have that $(1+x^2)^n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ a.e..  Hence, by L'Hopital rule, $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2nx}{2nx (1+x^2)^{n-1}} \to 0$ a.e.

Moreover, $|f_n(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x$ so we may apply Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem to conclude that $ \int f_n(x) dx \to 0$.

Comment: For L'Hospital, should you not differentiate with respect to $n$? Since you show pointwiese convergence for every $x\in [0,1]$ hence you consider the limit by fixing $x$ and letting $n\rightarrow \infty$? I might be missing something...